# Error when trying to use Google OAuth 2.0 login hybrid flow (Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: '0'')

Tags: php, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to implement a "Sign-in using G+" button using the server-side hybrid flow and I keep getting the same error :

```
Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: '0'
```

I have looked everywhere, tried everything, I can't fix it.
I am using the latest version of Google PHP Client Library from GitHub (last updated on May 17th).
I checked a zillion times if my client_id & client_secret were correct.

Here's my code :

```
set_include_path("C:\wamp\www\src" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

include_once '../config/config.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Plus.php';



$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");

if (isset($_REQUEST['storeToken'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
      $client->authenticate($_POST['code']); // ERROR
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        unset($_SESSION['logout']);
    }
}
```

I tried a cURL request with the `code` parameter obtained after the user logs in.

```
curl --data code=4%2F3dZSVbozE_Kd4Sdf85KHPln-wChQ.ojCViNnNCQcYYKs_1NgQtmXZbUwqjAI&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=postmessage&client_id=<my_client_id>&client_secret=<my_client_secret> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

It works perfectly, I get this :

```
{
  "access_token" : "ya29.GwAwNLxa5vExHxoAAACkL-MxCUL7K6SlOLSs2DNWCBipZcpyYwcOohejabVBYg",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3565,
  "id_token" : "<very_long_id_token>",
  "refresh_token" : "1/4Tj6y6yCQQFH2XzrLumNqMmurAr4Ik0pooF4nrhe1Zk"
}
```

I first thought that some parameter of my request was wrong, because very oddly, the libary keeps returning the same error (Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: '0') even if a parameter is wrong (I tried `$client->authenticate('This is not a valid code');` ) or if the requests to google.accounts returns a uri_mismatch. Is that normal ?

I hope somebody can help, because I don't know what to do :/

Thank you very much !

PS : I am running these tests using WAMP Server 2.4 (PHP Version 5.4.12)

Comment: What is your $redirect_uri set to?  I don't think its that but i'm just wondering.

Comment: @DalmTo I set it to "postmessage".

`$redirect_uri = 'postmessage';`


I also tried to set it to the URL of my page (and modify the redirect_uri in Google Developpers console).

But I don't think it's the problem, because when I tried (on purpose) a wrong redirect_uri, the request (using cURL) clearly returned redirect_uri_mismatch.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial for this?  Your code doesn't look anything like anything I have seen before. But then I haven't tried the plus.login before. I am surprised that its so different then the other Google APIs

Comment: Yep, I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.gvngroup.be/doc/Google/google_plus_sign_in_tutorial.php), but it's in french (sorry).

But I've read many many tutorials on the subject and they all use the same ideas.
See (in English this time) [this tutorial](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-google-account-oauth_231.html).

I found tutorials on developpers.google.com very poorly documented. They only show snippets and don't explain everything.
I also tried to use their "quickstart example for PHP" which led to the same error.

Comment: Link to the tutorial please :)

Comment: Yep, sorry. I edited my previous comment :)

Comment: That's Part of your problem both of them are using the Old Google PHP client lib.  The New Google PHP Client lib can be found https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.  There aren't any examples for that in the project though.   If you don't mind waiting I can see if I can get a working example for you tonight.

Comment: Yes, maybe it doesn't help. But the version used in the first tutorial seems pretty recent. Today, I'm trying to upload my code to a "real" (online) server to see if that makes any difference.

If you have a know a detailed tutorial (walkthrough) using a recent version of the google-api-php-client, I'll be glad to read it :)

Comment: Okay, so now when I run these tests on an online server, it doesn't work either, but the error message is different. Now, I get :

`Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'`

When I try a cURL request using the `code` parameter obtained after requesting the first access, it doesn't work, and I get this error :

`{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Invalid code."
}`

Comment: So, in summary :
- on WAMPServer (local), I get a strange error but my `code` is valid (request works using cURL)
- on an online server, I get another error but this time my `code`is not valid. (Obviously, I modified my javascript origins parameter in Google Developpers Console).

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The other posting (similar to the above) refers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699484/problems-with-the-google-api-php-simple-query-example/23787500#23787500)

I finally resolved the issue by changing the following PHP.ini settings:

1. I set (by uncommenting) the extension=php_openssl.dll - necessary for 'https' URLs; and
2. I set the time-zone. Google is fussy about times, so this might have affected the outcome

I restarted Apache and all was well !!